# How to satisfy cocoapod external dependancy when using specific branch

Tags: cocoapods, swinject

In my project I'm using both Swinject and SwinjectAutoregistration pods. Both are usually declared as '2.0.0' versions like so: 

  `pod 'Swinject', '2.0.0'
  pod 'SwinjectAutoregistration', '2.0.0'`

But in order to build my project in the beta version of Xcode 9, I need to take a specific branch of the Swinject github repo, [as stated here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4373). The new declaration looks like this:

`pod 'Swinject', :git => 'https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject.git', :branch => 'swift4'`

When I then try `pod update` I have dependencies error. I believe SwinjectAutoregistration declares a dependency to Swinject 2.0 so I have different sources for the same pod.

Is there a way to tell cocoapods that this specific source of the pods *acts* like the 2.0 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like specifying the source as the github repo instead of the cocoapod repo for this particular pod works.

I added this line before the `target 'MyGreatApp' do` line:

`source 'https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject.git'`

I must specify that this works for this particular pod, but might not work for other cases. The fine folks behind Swinject have a fix for an Xcode (9, beta) bug on a branch in their github repo that is not in the cocoapod repo.

So this answer works in this case, but unfortunately this might not be as generic as I hoped.